# how to expand the file based on the numbers which have given in the input file?

Tags: perl

I have one input file

MOD_GlcNHglycan 264-268 DTSGT

I would like to have output as follow
MOD_GlcNHglycan 264 D
MOD_GlcNHglycan 265 T
MOD_GlcNHglycan 266 S
MOD_GlcNHglycan 267 G
MOD_GlcNHglycan 268 T

Answer (score 0):

```
my $str = 'MOD_GlcNHglycan 264-268 DTSGT';
my ($name, $range, $chars) = split ' ', $str;
my ($start, $end) = split '-', $range;
my @chars_arr = split '', $chars;
my @results = ();
foreach my $char ( @chars_arr ) {
    push @results, $name, ' ', $start++, ' ', $char;
}
```

Results in an array containing:

```
MOD_GlcNHglycan 264 D
MOD_GlcNHglycan 265 T
MOD_GlcNHglycan 266 S
MOD_GlcNHglycan 267 G
MOD_GlcNHglycan 268 T
```